# Why do I get results from a different row in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Using this query,

```
SELECT username, MAX(wordpermin) as maxword,date_created FROM user_records where DATE(date_created) = CURDATE() GROUP BY(username) ORDER BY maxword DESC LIMIT 20
```

I am trying to query a limit of 20 of the top `wordpermin` by their username and the time created and that by calling `date_created` in the current 24 hours.

The problem I have is when I have a new high `wordpermin`. Instead of giving me also the new `date_created`, it keeps the old value of `date_created`. I even looked into my database and I made sure I have `date_created` updated. How can this happen?

I mean, I have two values from different rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query gives you the last date where a user has the maxword.

Your query would not run when you activated ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

You should always specify for **every** column which [aggregation function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html) you want to use, because SQL rows don't have any order and every column will be selected on its own.

I selected Max (date_created), so that MySQL knows which date to show, because if there were more than one date with the same maximum word, MySQL would show all.

```
SELECT
    u.username, u1.maxword, MAX(u.date_created)
FROM
    user_records u
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
        username,DATE(date_created) date_created, MAX(wordpermin) AS maxword
    FROM
        user_records
    GROUP BY username,DATE(date_created)) u1 ON u.username = u1.username
        AND u.wordpermin = u1.maxword AND Date(u.date_created) = DATE(u1.date_created)
WHERE
    DATE(u.date_created) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY (username)
ORDER BY maxword DESC
LIMIT 20;
LIMIT 20
```

Examole http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/857355/2

Comment: i tried it and it didn't give me anything 0 results ?? also it's fine if it shows the same max if it's for different username.

Comment: can you provide sample data to check?

Comment: Have you checke the date is correct, that would be my first guess

Comment: yes i checked that in the db it's correct  this is an example 2020-04-03 08:10:48

Comment: i used  current_timestamp() to generate the time in date_created

Comment: Then show me please example data see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: this is a table http://shoppingshelter.com/data.php that shows the results of query: SELECT username, MAX(wordpermin) as maxword,date_created FROM user_records where DATE(date_created) = CURDATE() GROUP BY(username) ORDER BY maxword DESC LIMIT 20

Comment: See my link in the last comment plaese make an dbfiddle example

Comment: thank you so much this worked!! am really thankful :)

Comment: there is an issue with your query look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6b64a/1 if you hit run SQL it wont show anything even do the user 'mark' hit '68' wordpermin which is his max for today it refuses to show it ?

Comment: As i stated before your data only has records for the 3.4.2020 today is the 4 so no records show, which you can clearly see when you do first a SELECT 
    u.username,date_created
FROM
    user_records u    
    WHERE
    DATE(date_created) = CURDATE();  no data appears, remove the where clause and it shows all data.

Comment: sorry the link wasn't correct try this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8e80a/1 as you can see i made one record of 4 and it can't be showed using your query

Comment: Yes there was a problem with the maxvale because it tokk only the overall Maximum see my updated answer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8e80a/2

Comment: this still doesn't work see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/857355/1 i added a new record in the first row and see how it gets the date_created right but gets the maxword wrong instead of giving 69 it gives 68

Comment: thank you this seems to work thanks again for the help :)